# "PHP Error" when running PHPUnit tests from within Komodo IDE

Tags: php, phpunit, komodo

I am using the latest version of the Komodo IDE, PEAR and PHPUnit with PHP version 5.3.0. When I run the unit tests for my Komodo project the tests run correctly, but regardless of whether there are any tests to run or not I get shown the error:

```
---------------------------
PHP Error
---------------------------
parse error in Unknown on line 7

---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

Everything works fine despite this error but it is irritating to see every time I run my tests. Furthermore, running the unit tests from the command line does not trigger any kind of error, suggesting that this is a problem with Komodo.

How can I fix the error or, at the very least, stop it from showing up.